# Axios adds constant name as outline to JSON, how do I only send the body?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to send a POST request to a REST API that I have created. The POST request is sent from a Reactjs application.

The JSON I want to send looks like this:

```
{
   "name":"something"
}
```

My plan was to send it like this:

```
const json = {
    "name" : "something"
}

Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/", {json})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
})
```

But when I do that the JSON that is sent looks like this:

```
{
   "json"{
          "name":"something"
         }
}
```

an then the API can't process the request. Is there a way to only send the body of the constant? I know that I can send the request like this:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/", {"name":"something"})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
})
```

and that works, but I would like to send a bit more complicated JSON than just one hardcoded line. So, is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: Use `json` instead of `{json}` (which is short for the object literal `{json: json}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{}` is a new object.

`{json}` is a new object with a property named `json` that has the value of the variable of the same name.

If you don't want to wrap your data in a new object… don't.

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/", json)
```

---

NB: The value of the `json` variable is an object. It doesn't get turned into JSON until somewhere inside the Axios library. You should probably give it a more descriptive name (such as `brand`).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! The variable names were just created for this question, and won't be used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `{}` wrapping your object reference. The data argument expects an object and `json` already is one.

note that is a poor choice of variable names since it is not actually json data which is a string data format

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/", json)
```

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping json `{}` in brackets, (in the `Axios.post` call), you are making a nested json object. Removing those should fix the problem.